# How to sort the matrix by columns without changing its size in Python?

Tags: python, sorting, matrix

For example, considering the matrix:

`matrix=[[2,5,7],[6,3,1],[9,8,7]]`

Matrix sorted by columns is:

`matrix_sorted=[[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6,9]]`

When the matrix has a different number of rows and columns:

`matrix2=[[7,1],[2,6],[3,5]]`

Sorted matrix is:

`matrix2_sorted=[[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]]`

When getting all numbers from the matrix2 I get the list:

`numbers=[1,2,3,5,6,7]`

I tried making a new matrix and then transposing it:

```
n=3 //number of rows
m=2 //number of columns

new_matrix2=[]
for i in range(n):
    temp=[]
        for j in range(m):
        temp.append(numbers[0])
        numbers.pop(0)
    new_matrix.append(temp)

new_matrix2_T=[]
for i in range(m):
    column=[row[i] for row in new_matrix]
    reversed_matrix.append(column)
```

But transposing gets me a matrix of a different size:

`new_matrix2_T=[[1,3,6],[2,5,7]]`

Comment: These are all Lists of Lists. You would be better using Numpy arrays which do have the features of rows and columns.

Answer (score 0):

Your data is currently in a list of lists.

Personally I think that a list of lists is not a convenient data structure for what you are asking.

I suggest using a numpy array, which can easily be flattened, sorted, then reshaped.

Unfortunately, the standard numpy function / method to reshape an array tends to fill it by row, not columns. You can work around that by inverting height and width and then taking the transpose of the matrix.

```py
import numpy as np

def sorted_by_columns(mat):
    a = np.array(matrix)
    h,w = a.shape
    a = np.sort(a.ravel()).reshape((w, h)).T
    return a

matrix=[[7,1],[2,6],[3,5]]

sorted_mat = sorted_by_columns(matrix)

print(sorted_mat)
# [[1 5]
#  [2 6]
#  [3 7]]
```

Documentation:

- [.reshape](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape);
- [.ravel](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.ravel.html);
- [.T](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.T.html#numpy.ndarray.T);
- [numpy.sort](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html).